# How to optimize assignment of tasks to agents with these constraints?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, np

I have an assignment problem as a part of my Master's Thesis, and I am looking for general direction in solving the same.

So, there is a list of agents, and a list of tasks, with number of tasks being greater than the number of agents.

The agents submit a prioritized ordered list of tasks they can/want to do. The length of the list is fixed to a number much smaller than the total number of tasks.

Every agent must be assigned a task. A task once assigned cannot be assigned to another agent.

The objective is to find an assignment such that the average priority/preference of the assigned tasks is the lowest. Additionally, if it is complete solution i.e. every agent is assigned a task, it is even better.

I have looked at the generalized assignment problems, and the Hungarian algorithm, but these do not cater to the specific situation where there is a cost to a task and also the possibility of the agent being unable to do some of the tasks.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried creating null "do nothing" tasks so that an answer can include "this agent does nothing" and null "outsourced" workers so that the an answer can include "no agent here does this task"?

Comment: The problem is the same as assignment problem if we model the priorities as costs (most preferred has a cost of 1, then 2, then 3 and for the tasks not in the priority list, cost is infinity). You can then add dummy agents to make the number of agents and tasks equal and solve it using the Hungarian Algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a general approach, you can model the problem as Mixed Integer Program, introducing binary variables for the assignment of tasks to agents and putting the priority costs and (very high) non-assignment costs into the objective function. Mixed Integer Programs can be solved using a variety of solver programs, including CPLEX or Gurobi which are free for academic purposes.