# Mapping 2D points to a fixed grid

Tags: algorithm, grid, 2d

I have any number of points on an imaginary 2D surface. I also have a grid on the same surface with points at regular intervals along the X and Y access. My task is to map each point to the nearest grid point.

The code is straight forward enough until there are a shortage of grid points. The code I've been developing finds the closest grid point, displaying an already mapped point if the distance will be shorter for the current point.

I then added a second step that compares each mapped point to another and, if swapping the mapping with another point produces a smaller sum of the total mapped distance of both points, I swap them.

This last step seems important as it reduces the number crossed map lines. (This would be used to map points on a plate to a grid on another plate, with pins connecting the two, and lines that don't cross seem to have a higher chance that the pins would not make contact.)

[image]

Questions:

1. Can anyone comment on my thinking that if the image above were truly optimized, (that is, the mapped points--overall--would have the smallest total distance), then none of the lines were cross?
2. And has anyone seen any existing algorithms to help with this. I've searched but came up with nothing.

Comment: My answer, provides answer for both of questions, but after a long discussion, it is not clear what was OPs goal. E.g. if he knews answer to the first question, then why he asked it? Or e.g. I explained to have a good heuristics he should make multiple passes of removing crossings and mathematically I show why this is required and why it works. In Q, it is written he makes only one pass of refinement. In comments at my post he wrote he don't see why multiple passes required, after I put the picture he says he knew it. Sorry, neither a real Q nor a real OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be approached as a variation of the [Assignment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), with the "agents" being the grid squares and the points being the "tasks", (or vice versa) with the distance between them being the "cost" for that agent-task combination. You could solve with the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

To handle the fact that there are more grid squares than points, find a bounding box for the possible grid squares you want to consider and add dummy points that have a cost of 0 associated with all grid squares.

The Hungarian algorithm is O(n<sup>3</sup>), perhaps your approach is already good enough.

See also:

[How to find the optimal mapping between two sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918259/how-to-find-the-optimal-mapping-between-two-sets)

[How to optimize assignment of tasks to agents with these constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25218315/how-to-optimize-assignment-of-tasks-to-agents-with-these-constraints)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your main concern correctly, minimising total length of line segments, the algorithm you used does not find the best mapping and it is clear in your image. e.g. when two line segments cross each other, simple mathematic says that if you rearrange their endpoints such that they do not cross, it provides a better total sum. You can use this simple approach (rearranging crossed items) to get better approximation to the optimum, you should apply swapping for more somehow many iterations.

In the following picture you can see why crossing has longer length than non crossing (first question) and also why by swapping once there still exists crossing edges (second question and w.r.t. Comments), I just drew one sample, in fact one may need many iterations of swapping to get non crossed result.

This is a heuristic algorithm certainly not optimum but I expect to be very good and efficient and simple to implement.

[image]

Comment: The problem I'm having is that I do a second pass where I compare the sum of two already mapped points with the same sum if the two points swap their mapping. I do this with each point against all other points, and then if a two points are swapped I add those two points to again be compared to all other points for possible swaps. And yet the result does not appear optimal. Still need more understanding of what is needed here.

Comment: @Jonathan, first of all if you want a P time algorithm, then as other answer suggests Hungarian algorithm works, but I think it is slow in your case. But if you want  good and fast heuristic algorithm then run the swapping algorithm for every crossing segments. This may cause new crossing segments but it has smaller total length. You should do this swapping for crossing segments with reasonable amount of iterations. Not just 2 times. It depends to the size of your input. E.g. if your input size is n do it n times. I guess It's way more faster than Hungarian and very very close to optimum.

Comment: Btw, one measure of goodness of any heuristic algorithm for this problem is as I said: count how many crossings do you have. I'm almost sure by doing n times swapping, you will get a very nice result. Note that each time the procedure may resolve O (n), crossings.

Comment: As I pointed out, I was trying to swap those pairs where the sum of their lengths would be less. As far as I can tell, that should be the same as uncrossing crossed points. So, I am trying to do that. But it turns out the question is "how?"

Comment: @Jonathan, maybe I don't understand you. Let's say you have a pair of points and their associated grid points. What's wrong or hard with swapping their associated grid points?

Comment: E.g. is your problem that you don't know how to find crossing pairs?

Comment: Ok, if my assumptions are correct, it looks like I'm having trouble finding ALL crossing pairs. I explained how I was doing it. Would love it if someone could show me how it's wrong.

Comment: @JonathanWood, what you are doing is not bad. The problem is that you make only two passes. You should do it iteratively in roughly speaking many passes. Like n passes not just two. I may draw a picture to show what happens.

Comment: Well, I've tried more passes and it doesn't help. And I don't see why any more passes are needed. I compare each point to every other point. And every point that is swapped gets an additional pass (until no more are swapped). I don't know what is missing there.

Comment: 1."if the image above were truly optimized,then none of the lines were cross ": YES.

Comment: 2. "And I don't see why any more passes are needed": This is clear from the second picture.

Comment: 3. "And has anyone seen any existing algorithms to help with this": What I suggested is an algorithm which is good, understand that what you explained in best scenario was not doing more than one pass after initialization and I, as a person who don't read your mind but read the text, provided something you didn't do.

Comment: I'm not sure where you've suggested an algorithm. You said to swap pairs where it makes the total lengths shorter, which I already described I was trying to do. Moreover, I've explained how each swapped point is then run another pass, so I am already attempting to address your suggestion that additional swaps may be needed. So I'm sorry but I'm not seeing what's new. I'm starting to think that there is something about the logic to get every pair that might be giving me trouble, and am considering algorithms that find the optimum swap rather than just taking the fist swap that is better.

Comment: @JonathonWood, first part of your comment is nonsense. I left three very explicit comments. For each of them you should have one simple yes no reply: yes the comment x is correct, or no the comment x is wrong. I feel this sort of conversation is very stupid. About second part of your comment: No there is no way to swap pairs in one pass and get the optimum answer (second part of pic + a bit imaginatiob). Either you should use another algorithm or just find somehow better swaps not optimum. Or if u really looking for optimum swapping without using simplex etc, then do the brute force!

Comment: It's really hard to hear where you are coming from. Why on Earth would you talk about a way to swap pairs in one pass *when I've been very clear that I'm using additional passes from the very start?* At any rate, I can only assume you've been insulted as you appear to now be insulting me. Sorry it didn't work out. We just aren't on the same page I guess.

Comment: @JonathonWood, I said once, answer by yes/no 3 numbered comments. It shouldn't be hard for you! If you don't answer and continue commenting like this,  it means sth.